# What is the most precise upper bound for the partitions funcion $p(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

In the paper "Asymptotic formulæ in combinatory analysis, 1918" Hardy and Ramanujan gave an upper bound $p(n) < \frac{K}{n}e^{2\sqrt{2n}}, K > 0$. Is this the best upper bound? What is $K$'s value?

Comment: Rademacher's formula is even better - see [here](https://aimath.org/news/partition/brunier-ono.pdf).

Comment: This upper bounds appears to be useful only in an asymptotic sense. If we want to upper bound tightly $p(n)$ in practice , we need a concrete expression. The result here means that for every positive $K$ , there is a threashhold $n$ from which on the upper bound works , but this is rather useless for practical approximations since we do not know how large $K$ must be for a given $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erdös proved the upper bound
$$
p(n)\le e^{\pi \sqrt{2n/3}},
$$
and Radmacher's formula for the partition function $p(n)$ is given by

$$p(n)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}(n)\sqrt{k}\left[\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\sinh\left(\frac{\pi}{k}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\left(x-\frac{1}{24}\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{24}}}\right]_{x=n}$$
where
$$A_{k}(n)=\sum_{h=0, (h,k)=1}^{k-1}e^{\pi i(s(h,k)-2n\frac{h}{k})}$$ and
$$s(h,k)=\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\frac{r}{k}\left(\frac{hr}{k}-\left\lfloor\frac{hr}{k}\right\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Here values of $p(n)$ can be obtained by rounding sufficiently accurate truncations of Rademacher's formula.

Comment: Thanks! Can you share a link with Erdös upper bound?

Comment: Erdös, P. (1942). On an elementary proof of some asymptotic formulas in the theory of partitions.
Ann. Math. 43(3): 437–450